# DateInput component auto-sets format of date to YYYY-MM-DD in record

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, react-final-form

My backend server gets date in timestamp in seconds.
I use parse() function in  for formatting data into timestamp (number) and it works. But if I'm trying to click outside input or press create/edit button, it unexpectedly calls a format() function that accepts data in YYYY-MM-DD (!) format, and then it makes a request to backend server that contains date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Is  component auto-format data into YYYY-MM-DD format while being inactive? How can I keep data in number value?

React-admin version: 3.19

Comment: You can override the format()-function just like parse().

But there is still a problem with this.. In an Edit-Form, if you have a DateTimeInput which gets filled in from the DB, and you DON'T change it and click save:
It will save to DB with the dafault string-formatting...(YYYY-MM-DD), instead of timestamp.. It will not use the parse or format-function at all.